# <Object> tag does not work in android webview

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview

The pdf file does not read from assert folder.

tag does not work in android webview

```
WebView webview = new WebView(this); 
string url = "file:///android_assets/test.pdf";
setContentView(webview); 
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
webview.loadUrl(url);
```

Want to load the below HTML file in webview.

Need to Load pdf, word, excel, ppt.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="css/jquery-ui.css"
        rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var fileName = "Tulips.txt";
            $("#btnShow").click(function () {
                $("#dialog").dialog({
                    modal: true,
                    title: fileName,
                    width: 540,
                    height: 450,
                    buttons: {
                        Close: function () {
                            $(this).dialog('close');
                        }
                    },
                    open: function () {
                        var object = "<object data=\"{FileName}\" width=\"500px\" height=\"300px\">";
                        object += "</object>";
                        object = object.replace(/{FileName}/g, "Files/" + fileName);
                        $("#dialog").html(object);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
    <input id="btnShow" type="button" value="Show PDF" />
    <div id="dialog" style="display: none">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Kindly let me know if any other possibilities to convert PDF, Word & Excel into HTML with help of android webview.

Answer (score 0):

Your URL would appear to be to to a PDF. `WebView` cannot display a PDF.

Comment: Is there any other possibility to load docx, ppt,xls in android webview? @CommonsWare

Comment: @karthick: Convert them to HTML first.

Comment: @karthick: `WebView` has nothing to do with converting file formats into HTML. You will need to find other software to do that on your server (e.g., `unoconv`). Or, launch the documents into standalone viewers (e.g., Adobe Reader). Or, purchase licenses for commercial libraries that allow you to view those file formats within your app (though not involving `WebView`, most likely).

Comment: Actually my task is.. Need to open pdf word image etc.. without any external app(like Adobe Reader, MS Office).. So i am trying to open in webview.

Comment: @karthick: Then convert those files into HTML using some software on your server. Or, purchase licenses for commercial libraries that allow you to view those file formats within your app.

Comment: I need  open source.. How to Convert in to Html and then load that??